# Use of who id and what id in flows

Tags: visual-workflow

what is the relevance of using who id and what id in flows?
Why can't one use recordid? Please can someone tell the difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who Id, What Id and the Record Id are three different things with different purposes.

The Record Id is the field that Salesforce automatically fills for you once you insert the record. The value is unique for that record and it can't be changed. You use the Record Id if you want to reference a specific record.

The WhoId and the What Id on the Task object are polymorphic relationship fields. A relationship field is a field that you use to relate one record to another record. With normal relationship fields you are limited to only one specific object type. With polymorphic relationship fields you can link the Task record to different types of records. The Who Id can be linked to Contacts or Leads. The What Id can be linked to other objects like accounts, opportunities or custom objects.

To fill the Who Id or What Id on Task you use the Record Id of whatever record you want to link. This can be done manually or in a flow.